# Write a test for SQL Server using EF in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, testing

I'm trying to test the below function using Nunit:

```cs
public static void Create(Contact contact)
{
    using (var db = new PhonebookContext())
    {
        db.Database.EnsureCreated();

        try
        {
            db.Contacts.Add(contact);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully added {contact.Name}!"); 
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Helpers.CreateErrorMessage, contact.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my current test:

```cs
[Test]
public void Create_Contact_DbRowIsAdded()
{
    var contact = new Contact { Name = "Abhinav", PhoneNumber = 1234567890, };
    SqlAccess.Create(contact);
    
    Assert.Equals(contact, SqlAccess.GetLastContact());
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

If it helps, here's the code for the `dbContext` (which I believe the test has no access to):

```cs
public class PhonebookContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts => Set<Contact>();
    
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        try
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(System.Configuration
                .ConfigurationManager
                .ConnectionStrings["SQLServer"]
                .ConnectionString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An unknown error occurred while creating the database. Please make sure SQL server is running.");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The function works perfectly, except when it is put through the test.

Am I missing something?

Comment: NUnit is for _unit tests_, but you're writing an integration test.

Comment: Interesting. So switching to something like xUnit would solve my problem?

Comment: xUnit is also for unit tests, not integration tests. Generally speaking integration tests require you to build your own test infrastructure and runners - while Microsoft [does have some integration-test libs for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests) I'm not aware of any for EF and SQL Server, especially not any that will manage DB state for you (i.e. snapshotting, comparing tables to expected data, rolling back (or forward) to a known state when running complex tests, or concurrent runs, etc).

Comment: No, I can't. SO is not a forum for recommendations to other resources.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you do not provide in your's PhonebookContext the db configuration for Contact class (which is db entry i guess).

So in order to fix that you should do something simmilar:

```
        internal class ContactDbConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
        {
            public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TaskDto> builder)
            {
                // register your properties of contact class here for example: 
                builder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            }
        }
```

And please add on model creating method in your PhonebookContext:

```
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactDbConfiguration());
    
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }
```

Finally your dbContext should be like this:

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // your code here
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactDbConfiguration());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I still get the same error

Comment: @Abhinav what kind of approach are you using? code first or db first?

Comment: I'm using a code first approach